# How to convert char string to character in C#

Tags: c#, string, escaping, character

I am trying to read character from input and convert it to the character's int value.
The input string is in format `'[character value]'`.

I can do
`((int)input.ToCharArray()[1])`
However this does not account for escape sequences (for example \0 for hex 0x00)

Is there a way to convert a string to a character taking into account the escape sequences? (and also, is there a way to convert a string in format `"[string value]"` to string taking into account escape sequences as well?)

Comment: Please provide some (multiple) examples of the input and the expected output.

Comment: All escape chars will end up with and int value < 32, so you can just remove those after conversion.

Comment: Your code correctly returns `0`. What do you want it tu return? The value of character `0` ignoring the escape sequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is only one actual character that may be a *literal* escape-sequence, it's surrounded by single quotes and brackets. Then I guess you could use a sneaky regex escape.

```
var input = "'[\0]'";
var trimmed = input.Substring(2,input.Length-4);
var escaped = Regex.Escape(trimmed);
var theByte = (byte) escaped[0];
Console.WriteLine(theByte);
```

[Demo here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LxUXhE)

<sub>***Note**: There are a lot of assumptions here, and there may be a better way to do this, and this may have issues I'm not aware of.*</sub>

Comment: this will not work for `input = "[]]"`

Comment: @GuruStron ahh yess good point, maybe best to go with your substring

Comment: `s.Substring(2, s.Length - 4); // or other way to strip '[ and ]', like regex` yes, sure)